# Adding rows in Excel via ADO

Tags: excel, vbscript, ado

I am having a problem updating an Excel worksheet using ADO via VBScript.

The test workbook contains 3 worksheets: Sheet1, Sheet2, & Sheet3.

I use the "INSERT" and "AddNew" methods to update each worksheet.

If the header row contains more than one column the heading row format is retained in the new rows.

If the header row contains only one column then a row is skipped but the heading row format is not retained in the new rows.

This doesn't make sense!  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Attached is a image of the script and the resulting worksheets.

```vb
    Option Explicit
'****
'*  Test updating (INSERT and ADDNEW) an MS-Excel worksheet using ADO.
'****
    Dim oADO
    Set oADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        oADO.Mode = 3 '=adModeReadWrite
        oADO.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1,ReadOnly=False';Data Source=excel.xls"
       '*
        oADO.Execute   "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (Comment) VALUES ('INSERT')"
       '*
        oADO.Execute   "INSERT INTO [Sheet2$] (Comment) VALUES ('INSERT')"
       '*
        oADO.Execute   "INSERT INTO [Sheet3$] (Comment) VALUES ('INSERT')"
    Dim oRST
    Set oRST = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        oRST.ActiveConnection = oADO
        oRST.CursorType = 2 '=adOpenDynamic
        oRST.LockType = 2 '= adLockPessimistic
       '*
        oRST.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
        oRST.AddNew
        oRST.Fields("Comment").Value = "ADDNEW"
        oRST.Update
        oRST.Close
       '*
        oRST.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]"
        oRST.AddNew
        oRST.Fields("Comment").Value = "ADDNEW"
        oRST.Update
        oRST.Close
       '*
        oRST.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet3$]"
        oRST.AddNew
        oRST.Fields("Comment").Value = "ADDNEW"
        oRST.Update
        oRST.Close
    Set oRST = Nothing
        oADO.Close
    Set oADO = Nothing
```

[VBScript code and results in worksheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEFOt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the file already exists and there is already some blank data there? I tried a version of your script which runs `CREATE TABLE` to create the worksheets before the inserts and I'm not seeing the blank rows.

```
Option Explicit

dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fso.FileExists("excel.xls") then
    fso.DeleteFile "excel.xls"
end if


'****
'*  Test updating (INSERT and ADDNEW) an MS-Excel worksheet using ADO.
'****
Dim oADO
Set oADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oADO.Mode = 3 '=adModeReadWrite
    oADO.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1,ReadOnly=False';Data Source=excel.xls"

oADO.Execute "CREATE TABLE Sheet1 (comment text)"
oADO.Execute "CREATE TABLE Sheet2 (comment text)"
oADO.Execute "CREATE TABLE Sheet3 (comment text)"


   '*
    oADO.Execute   "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (Comment) VALUES ('INSERT')"
   '*
    oADO.Execute   "INSERT INTO [Sheet2$] (Comment) VALUES ('INSERT')"
   '*
    oADO.Execute   "INSERT INTO [Sheet3$] (Comment) VALUES ('INSERT')"
Dim oRST
Set oRST = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    oRST.ActiveConnection = oADO
    oRST.CursorType = 2 '=adOpenDynamic
    oRST.LockType = 2 '= adLockPessimistic
   '*
    oRST.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    oRST.AddNew
    oRST.Fields("Comment").Value = "ADDNEW"
    oRST.Update
    oRST.Close
   '*
    oRST.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]"
    oRST.AddNew
    oRST.Fields("Comment").Value = "ADDNEW"
    oRST.Update
    oRST.Close
   '*
    oRST.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet3$]"
    oRST.AddNew
    oRST.Fields("Comment").Value = "ADDNEW"
    oRST.Update
    oRST.Close
Set oRST = Nothing
    oADO.Close
Set oADO = Nothing
```

Comment: No.  The workbook exists with three worksheets and each has only a header row.

Comment: fair enough :-)